# To show checkboxes in a particular row on button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview with a linkbutton in each row, on link button click, I want to show checkboxes for the cells in that particular row in which button is clicked,also want to keep them (checkboxes) checked or unchecked according to value in that particular cell.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: k.. it is possible. first user click the link the check box will appeare then user can check or uncheck the check box. then the user click another link button then previous check box should be hiden or not. the check box is present in gridview or dynamically need to bind.

Comment: for what reason u need to show checkboxes in a perticular row on button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't will to do your work, but I can give to you some ideas...

- With Jquery
- set a event handler for your links: `$(selector).click(function(){...});`
- inside the function, try to get the row parent object of the link button: `var tr = $(this).parent('tr');`
- get and iterate all the columns of the row: `$.each(tr.find('td'), function(i, td){...})`
- for each column prepend or append a new checkbox element, checked or not: `td.prepend('<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>');`

Try to coding...